# Querying for 1 to 1 Records in Table

Tags: t-sql

Simplifying a table 'Summary' to 2 columns: CoID, Type

There can be multiple types per CoID:

```
-----------
CoID | Type
-----------
150  | 2
150  | 5
233  | 2
120  | 1
120  | 2
```

I want to get a count of CoIDs that have only 1 Type. In this case CoID 233 would be the only one I'd want selected.

Thanks!

Comment: which rdbms are you using?

Comment: @eltomato As he tagged tsql so I guess OP is talking about SQL Server. However, question is bit unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Having clause from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

```
SELECT COUNT(Type), COID
FROM Customers
GROUP BY COID
HAVING COUNT(TYPE) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Group by` with `Having` clause for filtering:

```
SELECT COID, COUNT(Type)
FROM SUMMARY
GROUP BY COID
HAVING COUNT(COID) = 1
```

OUTPUT:

```
COID |  COUNT(Type)
=====|=================
233  |  1
```

[Live DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gEgsgRq4SuoMFwRt5UCJ78/0)